# Generic Array Adapter for Alternate Row Color?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to develop a Generic Array Adapter Class from which i like to inherit the row color property for odd and even rows. My Generic Adapter Class is

```
public class SpecialAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30FF0000, 0x300000FF };

    public SpecialAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> items) {
        super(context, resource,items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

And i like to extend this to my Adapter class to change the row color.

public class MyArrayAdapter extends SpecialAdapter{..}

Is it possible? Currently it is not displaying any colors. I am not setting any colors in my Adapter class. All i need is to inherit the row color from the base class so that i can use this for different Adapter class.

This is my adapter class

```
public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<MyObject> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.mylayout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);          
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).txtName.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.txtName.setText("Position " + position);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: if (position % 2 == 0){set one color}else{set another one}

Comment: the code looks good to me. Can you try with full alpha ? FF instead of 30?

Comment: I tried using full Alpha.. but no luck..

Comment: are you sure you are using this `SpecialAdapter`?

Comment: Try defining colors in values/color.xml `private int[] colors = new int[] { R.color.red, R.color.blue};` to discard problems with colors definition, alpha, ...

Comment: @JuanjoVega those are  color's id.

Comment: Whatever. English is not my mother tongue, so sometimes I say stupid things. Sorry

Comment: so you are using another adapter. Where are you setting the view's background color in the adapter you are using?

Comment: I've updated my question with my adapter class. Please check that.

Comment: @Blackbelt yes i am extending SpecialAdapter<MyObject>

Comment: well yes you are extending it, but you are not call super.getView(..) and even though, in your subclass you are inflating a different layout

Comment: Ok. So it means though the class is generic you need to have a predefined resource? cant we pass the layout dynamically?

Comment: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/

Comment: Please go through the above link they used a simple adapter but passing the layout dynamically..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tweaking as includeMe suggested and its working now. I can pass my layout as dynamic.

```
public class SpecialAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30FF0000, 0x300000FF };
    int resource;
    Activity context;
    List<T> items;

    public SpecialAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<T> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.context = context;
        this.items =items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        View view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(resource, null);
        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
        return view;
    }

}
```

And added this line in my Adapter class getView method.

```
view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

by replacing this line.

```
 view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
```

Now i no need to keep the color changing code in every adapter class. Superclass will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such generic method. You can use the following if there are only 2 color.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);  
    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  // you can add any color here
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);  // don't like cyan? add another color.
    }

    return view;  
    }
```

Comment: So its better to keep the row color change in adapter class itself.

Comment: Let's keep life simple, keep it in the adapter class itself if there are no other complications.